# How to force mac os x server 5.2 to use TLS 1.2 only

Tags: tls1.2, osx-server

I have a Mac running OS X Server 5.2 and due to company policy I need to force the server to use TLS 1.2 only and turn off TLS 1 and TLS 1.2.

I have edit the conf files in the /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites to SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2 but it still allows connection with tls1 and tls1.2

Does anybody know how to enforce TLS 1.2 connections only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If that is an option, update your Server app. Starting with Server version 5.3, support for TLS 1 and TLS 1.1 has been disabled by default, so this solution would be simple and effective.

If you cannot update for some reason, you will have to remove these protocols in `/Library/Server/Web/config/proxy/apache_serviceproxy.conf`, <s>and possibly in `/library/server/web/config/apache2/httpd.conf`. Also note that I have found that you have to restart macOS in order to restart the proxy server (it is not sufficient to issue `sudo serveradmin stop/start web`).</s> This seems to be unnecessary - see my update below!

---

### Update

It looks like there is a [bug in Apache](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60739) that can prevent the above setting from working as expected. It seems that, if there ciphers active that are not allowed any more in TLS 1.2, the older TLS versions remain available despite the setting in SSLProtocol. These older cipher suites need to be deactivated as well.

Therefore, use this recommended configuration:

```
   SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
   SSLCipherSuite ALL:+HIGH:!ADH:!EXP:!SSLv2:!SSLv3:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!NULL:!aNULL
   SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

Besides that, it looks like it's enough to update `/Library/Server/Web/config/proxy/apache_serviceproxy.conf`, as SSL/TLS is handled by the proxy process only. To restart the proxy use

```
$ sudo launchctl unload -w /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.serviceproxy.plist
$ sudo launchctl load -w /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.serviceproxy.plist
```

A server restart is not required.

There might be multiple occurrences in the configuration. I replaced them all, which may or may not be necessary.

Comment: I have tried using Mac OS X server 5.3 and 5.4 and on both the server is accepting TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.2 connections.  I have been using curl commands for testing:    
* SSL connection using TLSv1.0 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA

Comment: After I had updated from 5.2 to 5.3, TLS v1 was disabled for https. Did you update any conf files as described in my answer?